# Is the Angular Tutorial and its In-memory Web API following the correct PUT semantics?

Tags: angular, rest, api

I was following along the Angular tutorial and noticed the use of the *In-memory Web API*. All cool except for the code in the [PUT heroes method](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#add-heroserviceupdatehero) makes me uncomfortable.

Here it is:

```
private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';
...

/** PUT: update the hero on the server */
updateHero (hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateHero'))
  );
}
```

The thing to notice is that the PUT request is made to `this.heroesUrl` and not `this.heroesUrl/hero.id`. From my understanding when implementing CRUD over http, PUT should be made to the resource url.

**Is my understanding of PUT correct?**

In the above code it works because the `id` for the hero to update is `hero.id` which is part of `hero` object sent over PUT

For this simple hero model, the underlying API is auto-generated using the   [In-memory Web API](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api) package for the tutorial.

**If so, is the `In-memory Web API` generating the correct PUT semantics?**

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with you according to the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Relationship_between_URI_and_HTTP_methods) definition.

**`this.heroesUrl` is the link to the collection of heros**. The wikipedia definition for such resources is:

> Replace all the representations of the member resources of the collection resource with the representation in the request body, or create the collection resource if it does not exist.

This means when calling `this.heroesUrl`, we want to replace a collection with another collection. This is kinda incorrect because what they only update a single hero and fetch which one by looking at the body.

**It would be better to use `this.heroesUrl/${hero.id}`** in which case we are updating a specific resource. The wikipedia definition for this is:

> Replace all the representations of the member resource, or create the
>   member resource if it does not exist, with the representation in the
>   request body.

**You could open a bug report** in the [angular github repository](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues), they are usually pretty fast to change such things / provide reasoning why they did it this way.